# passing ‘const std::map<int, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, map

Когда пытаюсь прочитать значение карты `map` в методе класса с помощью `map[key]`, то получаю непонятную ошибку

> passing ‘const std::map’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

Что она означает?

добавил код

```
class Rectangle {
private:
    std::map<int, int> vertices;

public:
    Rectangle(const map<int, int>& vertices) {
        this->vertices = vertices;
    }

    void print_vertices() const {
        cout << vertices[0];
        cout << vertices[1];
        cout << vertices[2];
        cout << vertices[3];
    }

    // ...
};

int main() {
    Rectangle x{{{0, -34}, {1, 45}, {2, 92}, {3, 0}}};
    x.print_vertices();
}
```

Comment: Покажите фрагмент кода - со всеми объявлениями. Словом, поступите так, как пишут тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Harry Добавил код

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `[]` в `std::map` является *модифицирующим* оператором. Его не разрешается вызывать на константных `std::map`, о чем вам компилятор и говорит.

Для константных `std::map` существует метод `at`

```
void print_vertices() const {
    cout << vertices.at(0);
    ...
}
```

Имейте только в виду, что этот метод будет бросать исключения в ответ на несуществующий ключ.

Comment: так у меня карта неконстантая же, я без `const` её объявил

Comment: У вас сам метод `print` объявлен `const`. Внутри `const` метода все подобъекты вашего объекта будут видны как *константные* (если они не объявлены `mutable`)